# android - TabHost is blank in some activities and fine in others

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-tabhost

I am using a tabHost in certain layouts within my app and they work fine in certain activities but they show up blank in others. I've tried multiple setups but for some reason,the tabhost ends up blank in one activity but it works perfect in others.

Is there something I am missing....here's my code I am using to display my tabHost:

```
dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.maintabmenu);


    final TabHost tabs = (TabHost)dialog2.findViewById(R.id.my_tabhost);
    tabs.setup();
    tabs.setCurrentTab(0);

    TabSpec tspec11 = tabs.newTabSpec("New Tab");
    tspec11.setIndicator("User");

    tspec11.setContent(R.id.ScrollView01);
    tabs.addTab(tspec11);

    TabSpec tspec3 = tabs.newTabSpec("New Tab");
    tspec3.setIndicator("My options");
    tspec3.setContent(R.id.ScrollView03);
    tabs.addTab(tspec3);
    ///the reset of set up omitted
```

and then the xml:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/my_tabhost"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:padding="5dp">
       <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">

       <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout 
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:background="@drawable/bggreydotted"
                   android:orientation="vertical" >
               <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/usersname"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                     android:text="User Info" />
               <ImageView
                     android:id="@+id/profileimage2"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                     android:src="@drawable/favicon_yellow_g_metal_bg2" />
               <ImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/drawMark"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/createMarks"
                     android:background="@null"       
                     android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttondrawmark" />
              <ImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/zmLevel"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/search"
                     android:background="@null"        
                     android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonzoomlevel" />
              <ImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/license"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
                     android:layout_below="@+id/mypreferences"
                     android:background="@null"
                     android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonlicense" />
              <ImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/mapView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/zmLevel"
                     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                     android:background="@null" 
                     android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmapview" />
              <ImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/mypreferences"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/drawMark"
                     android:background="@null"        
                     android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonuserpreference" />
              <ImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/search"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/marksNearMe"
                     android:background="@null"        
                     android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmarksearch" />
              <ImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/createMarks"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:background="@null"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                     android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonuploadphoto" />
              <ImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/marksNearMe"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:background="@null"
                     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                     android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmarksnearme" />
           </RelativeLayout>
       </ScrollView>                
       <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView03"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">              
           <RelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/bggreydotted"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
              <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/userinfo"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                       android:text="USER INFO" />
              <ImageView
                       android:id="@+id/profileimage"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                       android:src="@drawable/favicon_yellow_g_metal_bg2" />
              <ImageButton
                       android:id="@+id/sky"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
                       android:layout_below="@+id/mymarks"
                       android:background="@null"
                       android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonsky" />
             <ImageButton
                       android:id="@+id/myclicks"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                       android:background="@null"
                       android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmyclicks" />
             <ImageButton
                       android:id="@+id/mygallery"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_below="@+id/myclicks"
                       android:background="@null"
                       android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmygallery" /> 
            <ImageButton
                       android:id="@+id/mymarks"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                       android:layout_below="@+id/mygallery"
                       android:background="@null"
                       android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmymarks" />
            <ImageButton
                       android:id="@+id/help"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
                       android:layout_below="@+id/createuser"
                       android:background="@null"
                       android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonhelp" />
            <ImageButton
                       android:id="@+id/createuser"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
                       android:layout_below="@+id/logout"
                       android:background="@null"
                       android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttoncreateuser" />
            <ImageButton
                       android:id="@+id/login"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                       android:background="@null"
                       android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonlogin3" />
            <ImageButton
                       android:id="@+id/logout"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                       android:layout_below="@+id/login"
                       android:background="@null"
                       android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonlogout" />
         </RelativeLayout>
      </ScrollView>                 
   </FrameLayout>
 </LinearLayout>    
</TabHost>
```

Comment: I use the same code in every activity as a menu yet in some places it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I ended up having to put my layout like so:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/my_tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">



              <RelativeLayout 
                  android:id="@+id/rlone"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bggreydotted"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/usersname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="User Info" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profileimage2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/favicon_yellow_g_metal_bg2" />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/drawMark"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/createMarks"
    android:background="@null"

    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttondrawmark" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/zmLevel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_below="@+id/search"
    android:background="@null"

    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonzoomlevel" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/license"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/mypreferences"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonlicense" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/zmLevel"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@null" 
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmapview" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mypreferences"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/drawMark"
    android:background="@null"

    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonuserpreference" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/marksNearMe"
    android:background="@null"

    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmarksearch" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/createMarks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonuploadphoto" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/marksNearMe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmarksnearme" />

</RelativeLayout>


               <RelativeLayout 
                   android:id="@+id/rltwo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bggreydotted"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userinfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="USER INFO" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profileimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/favicon_yellow_g_metal_bg2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/sky"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/mymarks"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonsky" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/myclicks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmyclicks" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mygallery"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/myclicks"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmygallery" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mymarks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mygallery"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmymarks" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/help"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/createuser"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonhelp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/createuser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/logout"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttoncreateuser" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonlogin3" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/login"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonlogout" />

</RelativeLayout>



    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```